# Create a new Dataframe with new or modify rows of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe in which new rows can be included, but I have to know if that new row that enters on the dataframe is a modification of some existing record, or if on the contrary, it is a new record.

For example, Input dataframe:

| A | B | Population | Start | End | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 300 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2025-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 250 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 350 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 2021-05-12 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 125 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |

In this case, rows 0,3 and 4 are new additions to the record since they do not have any similar date range between their same groups. The same group is the one with the same columns A and B.

However row 1 is a modification of row 2 since:

1. The timestamps is greater in register 1 than in register 2.
2. The start and end date intervals are "similar", that is, they are close to each other.

Expected Output:

| A | B | Population | Population_prev | Start | Start_prev | End | End_prev | Type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 300 | NaN | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | NaN | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | NaN | New | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 250 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | Mod | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 350 | NaN | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | NaN | 2021-05-12 00:00:00 | NaN | New | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 125 | NaN | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | NaN | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | NaN | New | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |

**Edit: to try to simplify it I will do the example with only one group A1 and B1**

For example, Input dataframe:

| A | B | Population | Start | End | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 300 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2025-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 250 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-06 00:00:00 |

For this specific case we have 3 records and as we can see in the timestamp there are two new records and one old record. Rows 0 and 1 are new records. Row 0 has time intervals that are not related to the other two, that is, the start and end dates, they are not close to the old record (since there are no interval overlaps between the old and new record) .

On the other hand, row 1 does have overlaps with the record of row 2, 2021-05-15, 2021-06-30  overlaps with 2021-05-30, 2021-06-02
So row 1 is a modification of row 2.

Expected Output:

| A | B | Population | Population_prev | Start | Start_prev | End | End_prev | Type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 300 | NaN | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | NaN | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | NaN | New | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 250 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | Mod | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |

Comment: *they are close to each other*: I understand but what is the rule to say that this value is close to the other?

Comment: @Corralien For example in rows 1 and 2 there is an overlap of time intervals since the end of row 1 is later but the beginning is earlier. On the other hand, you can see that row 0 dates are independent since they do not "share" an interval with rows 1 and 2.

Comment: I think the problem is under-specified: E.g. what happens if you have different predecessors ("prev") that are themselves not clearly ordered?

Comment: @Timus In this case you will only have a single predecessor at most for each record, in such a way that the modification will only take into account the last predecessor

Comment: Okay. Do you have a _hard_ definition of _close to each other_: Does that mean one interval is fully enclosed in the other? I've looked at one of your related older questions and am not fully convinced that that is the complete picture.

Comment: @Timus To be able to say that it is a modification, the new interval must contain or be contained in the other interval. That is, for example two dates like **ini: 2021-10-11 and end: 2022-07-10** could be a modification of **ini: 2021-10-05 and end: 2021-07-10**. Since the beginning of the two is very close (max 1 month). But it may also be the case that the end dates are close, or that the new interval is contained in the previous one. E.g. **ini: 2021-05-11 and end: 2022-07-10** mod of **ini: 2021-07-05 and end: 2022-07-10**

Comment: I'm still confused. Are `(21-03-15, 21-06-15)` and `(21-03-14, 21-06-14)` related? If so, how is the _direction_ of the relationship, or is it bi-directional, which would lead to the question of how to decide? Your definition _the new interval must contain or be contained in the other interval_ is symetrical, which leads to the same question of _direction_.

Comment: @Timus The first thing to do is look at columns A and B to know which record it is, and then thanks to the timestamp we can check which is the new record and which one is old on which we have to compare. Therefore once it is ordered by A, B and timestamps, we have to compare the intervals. If the interval with the highest timestamp is related (See E.G of the previous comment) with the interval with the lowest timestamp (of the same group A and B) It is a modification. I have edited the question to show it with examples.